# Laravel 5.0, migration: how to make integer not a primary key?

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

I would like to migrate a table with the elements below.

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('LoginID', 9)->unsigned();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60)->unique();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

However, I have kept dealing with the error below.
Does anyone know how to make integer "LoginID not a primary key so that I can migrate the table below? Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>         SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "users" has more than one primary key (SQL: create table "users" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "LoginID" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "username" varchar not null, "email" varchar not null, "password" varchar not null, "remember_token" varchar null, "created_at" date time not null, "updated_at" datetime not null))

Comment: Something is off. There is nothing in the migration you've shown that would cause LoginID to be an auto incrementing primary key.

Comment: I don't know the cause, but it worked a few hours later.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you use the function `->integer()` with a second param. According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_integer) the second parameter expects a boolean to set autoincrement or not: `bool $autoIncrement = false`).

Try this:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('LoginID')->unsigned();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60)->unique();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped me. I remove the second param from integer and It worked successfully.

Comment: Link to the documentation (api) didn't work (laravel version 5.2 api didnot exists) but 5.5 and above documentations (api) are present . i.e. https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_integer

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$table->integer('company_tel')->length(10)->unsigned();
```

or  this

```
$table->integer('company_tel', false, true)->length(10);
```

see details https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/why-am-i-getting-a-database-error-on-migration

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$table->increments('id', true);
```

This will auto increments the id without creating its primary key.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you call

```
$table->primary('id');
```

to mark id column as a primary key?

Comment: As you can see the query tries to make two primary keys: `"id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "LoginID" integer not null primary key autoincrement`

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it - doesn't `$table->increments('id');` mark it as a primary key too?